# Generate all combinations of elements

Tags: php, arrays, attributes, combinations

i have to generate all combinations of elements by unique value and in an orderly manner.
I explain with an example, these are the parameters and their values :

```
Dog : mal | female
Color : red | blue | yellow

the all combinations (ordered) to get are :
male - red
male - blue
male - yellow
female - red
female - blue
female - yellow
```

How can i do it in php using arrays ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I agree this is a poor question, but it would be kind if you downvote a new member, to leave some explanation.  Jojo, suggest you see the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I don't think I have ever seen a blue dog...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dogs = array( 'male', 'female');
$colors = array( 'red', 'blue', 'yellow');

foreach( $dogs as $dog)
    foreach( $colors as $color)
        echo $dog . ' - ' . $color . "\n";
```

**Output:**

```
male - red
male - blue
male - yellow
female - red
female - blue
female - yellow
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/WfgRiq)

Comment: Why was i good looking for more complicated ...? Thanks a lot for your fast reply nickb